# Regarding Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o

Tags: transfer

I have a 2TB Seagate Harddisk and during file transfer, the speed of transfer drastically reduces to 2 Mbps from say 150 Mbps.

Why is this happening so..??

I tried to format my 2TB Hard disk through Disks->more actions->format. But still, i am getting the reduction in transfer speed. My External Hard disk is USB 3.0.

Should i try Editing Partition..?? (My current Type is HPFS/NTFS(0X07)). What is the effect of this HPFS/NTFS..??

So how do i solve this issue..?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It's possible that your USB 3.0 port may not be supplying enough power for the Seagate 2TB hard disk. Do you have a different USB port that you can try? Do you have access to a **POWERED** USB hub that you can connect in between the Seagate and the computer's USB port? Does the Seagate have its own AC power brick?

Comment: I tried with different cable also... but still, it is giving a down performance while transferring data... And @heynnema I have no idea whether  Seagate 2TB external Hard disk has its own AC power Brick. How can i get the information of that..??

Comment: Actually, i formatted 2 times.. and now i can connect/mount the hard disk to my computer, but i can't copy paste or transfer even a single file to my external hard disk now... it is not copying at all...!!! Any suggestions regarding this..??

Comment: If the Seagate has has it's own power supply, it would plug into an AC power outlet in your home and supply high current +5 volts to the Seagate. Do you have  access to a powered USB hub, as I asked? Do you have another computer to try with the Seagate to see if it works there?

Comment: Yes, I tried with powered USB hub too and even with other computer.. but both in vain...

Comment: Then you may have either a defective external hard disk enclosure or power supply, or a defective Seagate hard disk drive. Try and remove the Seagate from the enclosure and attach it directly to a SATA port on one of your available computers, and see if it works by itself.